# Isomorphic finite rings?

Tags: ring-theory, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, ring-isomorphism

Let $p$ be a prime number, $P$ and $Q$ monic polynomial of degree $k\geq 2$, irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$.
Do we have $$\mathbb Z_{p^2}[x]/(P) \simeq \mathbb Z_{p^2}[x]/(Q)\ ?$$

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$? I'm asking since you're assuming that $P$ and $Q$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ instead?

Comment: With $\Bbb{Z}/(p^n)$ it works too (only one degree $k$ unramified extension of the $p$-adic integers) @lhf

Comment: By $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$, I mean the quotient of $\mathbb Z$ by $p^2\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb Z_p$, not $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f,g\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ of same degree, with their leading coefficient not divisible by $p$, and $f,g\in  \Bbb{Z}/(p)[x]$ irreducible.

- $R=\Bbb{Z}/(p^2)[x]/(f)$ has a unique maximal ideal $(p)$ and $R/(p)$ is the finite field with $p^{\deg(f)}$ elements
- by our knowledge of finite fields there is some $a\in R$ such that $g(a)=0\in R/(p)$,
- Hensel lemma : there is some $b\in R$ such that $g(a+pb)=0\in R$

  Proof: $g'\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ then $g'(a) \in R/(p)^\times$ (as $\gcd(g,g')=1\in \Bbb{Z}/(p)[x]$) which means that $ g'(a) \in R^\times, g(a+pb) = g(a)+pb g'(a)\in R$, and since $g(a)= pc\in R$ then $ b = -g'(a)^{-1}c$ gives $g(a+pb)=0\in R$.
- The map $y\to a+pb, \Bbb{Z}/(p^2)[y]/(g)\to R$ is an isomorphism